# File traverse and read failure in Vagrant / Puppet setup

Tags: vagrant, puppet

I have a Vagrant / Puppet set up in which I am attempting to generate a bunch of configuration files and then concatenate them into a master file.

The individual files are generated and written to a conf directory and the last action is to create the master file which uses an erb template to read the files in the conf directory.

```
<% files = Dir["/etc/sysconfig/iptables/conf/*.conf"] -%>
<% files.each do |name| -%>
<% file = File.open(name) -%>
<% contents = file.read -%>
<%= contents %>
<% end -%>
```

When I run "vagrant up", everything appears to run correctly but the master configuration file is empty. I have checked the timestamps on the conf directory and the master configuration file and they are correct to (The master config file is created after all the individual config files).

If I ssh into vagrant and run "puppet apply" manually, the master config file is created as expected. I have tried using a bash script instead of the erb method but encountered the same problems.

Does anyone have any ideas what might cause this?

Comment: I don't know why it fails, but I would try just writing exec with "cat /etc/sysconfig/iptables/conf/*.conf > $somefile"

Answer (score 2):

Puppet expands templates at manifest compile time. The content you are trying to catenate is only available at catalog application time.

Have you looked at the [concat](http://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/concat) module? It will likely make short work of your task.